# JavaScript Why does getItem() have two return types?

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

I am currently following a basic JavaScript Course and there was an example,
that confused me, because it seems that the getItem() function can have two return types.

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('name')) {
  setUserName();
} else {
  var storedName = localStorage.getItem('name');
  myHeading.textContent =storedName;
}
```

So in the if condition getItem returns true or false depending on wether there is an Item stored in the localStorage or not. And later the return value is stored in a variable as a String to output it on the website(in the "else" part). I googled for this and didn't find anything, but maybe I searched wrong, so I will be happy for any help I can get here. I don't know, if this code is enough to understand what I mean, but I will post more later on if necessary.

Comment: [`getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) returns a string.  Strings are considered ["truthy" in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: *"I googled for this and didn't find anything"* -- I didn't google for it but went straight to the documentation and found that [`Storage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) returns a string on success an `null` when the key is not present in the storage.

Comment: you're mixing up truthy/falsy values with real booleans

Comment: @Amy - except empty strings which are falsy (I see you clarified that in your answer, so, nevermind :p )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) returns:

> A DOMString containing the value of the key. If the key does not exist, null is returned.

And what is a [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString)?

> A DOMString is a UTF-16 String. As JavaScript already uses such strings, DOMString is mapped directly to a String.

So, it returns a `string`.  Strings (unless they are empty) are considered ["truthy" in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered  true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

So, in other words, if it returns a non-empty string, then the `if` statement considers it true.  If not, it's considered false.

This also means the conclusion you drew, that `getItem` has "two return types" is incorrect.  It has a single return type, and that type can be evaluated for truthiness.

Comment: Thank you so much! That explains everything, maybe I have to learn how to research properly.

Comment: @D.Jen sometimes the hardest part is simply knowing what to search for, or what invisible concepts are at play (by this, I mean "truthiness" is non-obvious).

Answer (score 0):

**[Storage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)**

> The *getItem()* method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name,
>   will return that key's value.

**Return value**

A DOMString containing the value of the key. If the key does not exist, null is returned.

---

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('name')) {
  setUserName();
} else {
  var storedName = localStorage.getItem('name');
  myHeading.textContent =storedName;
}
```

Your snippet will check if the local storage contains an item for the key 'name'. It will not return a boolean (true/false) but the object itself. If there's no value for the key, it will return 'null'.

`localStorage.getItem('name')` returns:

- **Null**: The script will execute the function `setUserName()`.
- **Any value**: The script will save the value under a variable called *storedName*.